# How to delete a folder named ${system:java.io.tmpdir}?

Tags: command-line, directory

I have a tmp type folder named ${system:java.io.tmpdir} and I couldn't delete it using regular command, rm -r, in terminal. Actually using tab, the terminal doesn't consider it as a folder and give no autocomplete!

how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper escaping, use any one of the following:

```
rm -r '${system:java.io.tmpdir}'
rm -r \$\{system:java.io.tmpdir\}
```

In `bash`, escaping just the `$` would do:

```
rm -r \${system:java.io.tmpdir}
```

You can not use double quotes here, like `rm -r "${system:java.io.tmpdir}` because the shell will then take the whole thing as variable expansion with the variable being `system:java.io.tmpdir`, which is in fact an invalid variable name, and then the expansion will always result in an empty string. So eventually, it would try to do: `rm -r ''`.